# Pandas find the duplicate data

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have data like this one, I want to got the results is order `b` and `c` are duplicated. How can I solve this problem? (Order and Item are multiple-index)

```
Order    Item     A
  a       1       'aaa'
          2       'bb'
  b       1       'aaa'
          2       'bb'
          3       'c'
  C       1       'aaa'
          2       'bb'
          3       'c'
```

Comment: Please **show** us the desired output, as your description is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create tuples of column `A` per first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
s = df.groupby(level=0)['A'].apply(tuple)
print (s)
Order
a         ('aaa', 'bb')
b    ('aaa', 'bb', 'c')
c    ('aaa', 'bb', 'c')
Name: A, dtype: object
```

And then return indices of all duplicated values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
out = s.index[s.duplicated(keep=False)]
print (out)
Index(['b', 'c'], dtype='object', name='Order')
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 1, 10, 20], [1, 2, 30, 40], 
                        [1, 3, 50, 60], [2, 1, 10, 20], 
                        [2, 2, 30, 40], [2, 3, 50, 60],
                        [3, 1, 10, 20], [3, 2, 30, 40],
                        [4, 1, 10, 20], [4, 2, 30, 40]], columns=['id', 'date', 'd1', 'd2']) 
print (df)

s = df.groupby('id')['d1','d2'].agg(tuple)
print (s)
              d1            d2
id                            
1   (10, 30, 50)  (20, 40, 60)
2   (10, 30, 50)  (20, 40, 60)
3       (10, 30)      (20, 40)
4       (10, 30)      (20, 40)

out = s.reset_index().groupby(s.columns.tolist(), sort=False)['id'].apply(tuple).tolist()
print (out)
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: Wow! this one can work, but this just one simple part, cause I have a lot of data. just like  >> df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 1, 1, 2], [2, 2, 3, 4], [3, 1, 5, 6], [3, 2, 6, 7], [4, 1, 5, 6], [4, 2, 6, 7]], columns=['id', 'date', 'd1', 'd2']) . then the first i set index >> df.set_index(['id', 'date'], inplace=True) , and then I use your way, got the result is >> Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64', name='id'), but I what I want is split them just like the result is [(1,2), (3,4)] . Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ jezrael Thanks a lot, almost solve my problem. only the result, I want to specify the result as [(1,2), (3,4)], these 2 are different group. anyway, this are great solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple. You should convert to Dataframe from groupby object and then use method.

```
df = df.reset_index()
df.drop_duplicates(keep = 'first', inplace = True)
```

If you need to filter by specific columns then

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset = [col1, col2, ...], keep = 'first', inplace = True)
```

**EDIT**

To keep duplicated:

```
df = df.groupby('Order')['A'].apply(list).reset_index()
df = df[df.duplicated(subset = ['A'], keep = False)]
```

If you want just a list of orders

```
list_orders = df['Order'].unique()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don`t want to drop the duplicate data, I want to filter out them. And only get the duplicate result and package them (b,c), if use your way the order 'a' also will be drop, so this can not solve my problem

Comment: @Starry  check this out

Comment: Still not, may be, cause for this case. I don`t think order 'a' any records are duplicate. and only think order b and c are duplicte, case they have entirely same value in column A

Comment: @Starry Yeaahhh, I changed to subset = ['A']. Should work now

Comment: @paverltr Thanks, but by this way, the order 'a' still in consider as True, can not just use duplicated